# ESRI Feature Layer Labels from REST endpoint

Tags: arcgis-rest-api, rest

I am using folium and calling this layer:

https://spatial-gis.information.qld.gov.au/arcgis/rest/services/PlanningCadastre/LandParcelPropertyFramework/MapServer/19

What am I hoping to do is use the dynamic layers options to include labeling. From the endpoint, I see that  `"hasLabels": true` however `"labelingInfo": null` so not sure what to make of that?

This is the relevant part of my script, the result is the polygons showing up fine sans labels.

```
dynamic_layers_string = '[{"id":19,"definitionExpression":"where=lga+%3D+%27 Burdekin+Shire%27", \
                         "source":{"type":"mapLayer","mapLayerId":19}, "showLabels":true,' \
                         '"labelingInfo":[{"labelPlacement":"esriServerPolygonPlacementAlwaysHorizontal",' \
                         '"labelExpression":"["locality"]",","useCodedValues":false,' \
                         '"symbol":{"type":"esriTS","color":[0,0,0,255],"font":{"size":56,"fontFamily":"Arial",' \
                         '"fontStyle":"normal","fontWeight":"bold","fontDecoration":"none"}]'

brisbane_suburbs = fr'https://spatial-gis.information.qld.gov.au/arcgis/rest/services/' \
                   r'PlanningCadastre/LandParcelPropertyFramework/MapServer/19/query?' \
                   r'where=lga+%3D+%27 Burdekin+Shire%27' \
                   fr'&dynamicLayers={dynamic_layers_string}&f=geojson'
```